# Hi, I'd like to find a plugin for Sublime Text 2 for auto-closing html tags

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

What I really want for the method of the auto-closing is that when I input

```
<tag>
```

then  becomes

```
<tag></tag>
```

.

The "tag" plugin of the Sublime Text 2 is like the Dreamweaver style, not the Coda 1 Style.
Is there any plugin or method, or a new text editor that can do this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137940/short-cut-for-close-html-tag-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 11):

It works out of the box, you just don't type in '<' nor '>'.
Simply enter any HTML tag name (a, html, body, div, img, ...) and press 'Tab', it will auto-complete and so `div` after you press 'Tab' will become `<div></div>`