# Short cut for close HTML tag in Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, sublimetext2

Is there a shortcut to close the HTML tag you've just opened in sublime text 2?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I just found out pressing

**For Mac:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

**For PC:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

**For Linux:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

will finish the tag you currently have open.

E.g. you type

```
<div>
```

Pressing the shortcut will give you

```
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was about to post this question. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Linux also uses the PC variant.

Comment: Thanks Shomz, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Does anyone else find this doesn't work with <style> and <script>?

Comment: I find no real reason to use (and need to remember) this command. Simply typing `</` once you're ready to close auto-completes the end tag. It's even somewhat HTML aware, meaning it's smart enough not to "close" a `<br>` tag in an open `<div>`. Maybe it's a newer feature, but I use this almost daily in ST3. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138019

Answer (score 51):

You can just type the type of tag you would like to insert and press tab!

**Examples:**

- Type `div` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get `<div></div>` with the cursor in the tag's content, and tab again to exit the tag.
- Type `a` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get `<a href=""></a>` with the cursor in the quotes, tab again to move to the tag's content, and tab again to exit the tag

Comment: This is the best way to do this. And if you use css selectors, your attributes will be auto-completed, too!

Comment: Even better: `div.my_class`, `div#my_id` or even `div.my_class#my_id` and then press `tab`

Comment: How about when inside <script> tag? (E.g. When using React.)

Comment: Ah, Babel and Babel Snippets packages helped. Never mind :-)

Comment: `Emmet` needs to be installed for this functionality for me

Comment: What an amazing! I have used the editor for more than 7 years without this awesome tool. and tips from @NabilKadimi are also awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Type div and then Tab. It automatically expands to  in sublime text 2.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Ctrl + Shift + <</strike> which is Edit > Tag > Close Tag

**UPDATE**

After seeing Rich's answer I remembered that I've changed the shortcut for this command.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the other people got their shortcuts from. On my version of Sublime Text 2, it's <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

Install "HTMLAttributes" package [here](https://github.com/agibsonsw/HTMLAttributes) or install it via Preferences > Package Explorer > Install Package