# Auto close end tag by typing ' </ ' in Sublime Text 2

Tags: autocomplete, tags, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 has a default key binding to close an elements end tag automatically by typing (Alt + .)

For example,

```
<h1> + (Alt + .), produces <h1></h1>
```

Default keybindings are accessible through Package Controller,

```
{ "keys": ["alt+."], "command": "close_tag" }
```

However, I'm not sure how to write it for `</`, as this would be two keys pressed  consecutively as appose to two keys pressed at the same time.

How can I rewrite the key binding to use `</`?

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check in your preferences file if the following line exists

```
"auto_close_tags": true,
```

It works for me in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: That worked! So no keybinding change necessary I guess. auto_close_tags was not even a default setting. I had to add it specifically to the user settings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im sorry... this did not actually work in Sublime Text 2. There was a combination of keybinding settings I had plus this fix that caused it to work, but only partially. it outputs an extra > on close of a tag like this, "<p><</p>".

I plan to review my home setup and provide an update to this ticket when I get something working... thanks anyhow.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137940/short-cut-for-close-html-tag-in-sublime-text-2